# How to insert variable value into database with Entity Framework and C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to insert the values of a bunch of variables into a database, how do I do that?

I have this code but cannot figure out how to use variables.

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new ASH_ORDER_DBEntities();

        var t = new ASH_PROD_ORDERS //Make sure you have a table called test in DB
        {
            Creator = "", Product = "", Created = "", Qty = "", Part_Number = "", Due = "", Edited = "", Ordered = null, Other = "", Urgent = null, Supplier = "",
        };
        context.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.Add(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please make your problem statement even more clear?

Comment: First, enclose ASH_ORDER_DBEntities in a using statement. Second: show us your classes and EF Configuration.

Comment: Where are your variables being defined? Essentially you need to replace the empty strings that you're assigning to the instance of `t` with the names of the variables you want to insert, but without more detail it's hard to say more than that.

Comment: i havnt defined my vars yet, but it will be things like var timeNow = datatime.now(); etc...

Comment: @GustavoF `using` statement is [not required](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/) with `DbContext`

Comment: @JamesMorrish: We can't give you a concrete answer if you do not show us a concrete example.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: True, but it's a good practice argument. Also, if you avoid the `using`, instantiate a db context in a method, and return an `IQueryable<>` (before any enumeration takes place) from that method, then you **may or may not** end up with problems when accessing the values (depending on whether the GC has decided to collect already, which can manifest as a bug that randomly appears and disappears). By using the `using`, you will at least run into _consistent_ errors.

Comment: @Flater manual creation of db context is not a good practice. You either have a single instance of context for the application lifetime (for desktop applications as above, or services) or you have a single instance of context per request for web applications. In both cases instance is injected by DI framework.In latter case, context instance should be disposed by DI framework instead of disposing it somewhere in the middle of request processing and having consistent errors. Btw I personally believe that returning `IQueryable` from DAL is a bad practice

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Returning it from the DAL, yes. Returning it from an internal method to another method inside the DAL, however, is acceptable (yet still prone to the same issues). Your comment is also overgeneralizing a bit (1) manual creation of db context does not inherently mean that a single context is used for the entire application's lifetime. (2) Manual creation of db context is relevant for some repositories where you want to add many entities (in separate method calls) but save them as a single transaction (3) UoW can be implemented without DI. Less ideal, but it is still done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?  It seems an odd question - you've got as far as having an EF context without knowing how to declare a local variable?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myCreator = CreatorTextBox.Text;
    string myProduct = ProductTextBox.Text;
    int myQty = QuantityEdit.Value;
    //....more vars...

    var t = new ASH_PROD_ORDERS
    {
        Creator = myCreator, 
        Product = myProduct, 
        Qty = myQty, 
        //... more 'Property = var' lines
    };
    context.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.Add(t);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yeah i was having a big brain fart moment, for some reason i thought i had to to something special when using variables and EF

Comment: Nah - all you're doing is creating an object...  the fact that the context does something weird and unspeakable with the object afterwards isn't something you need to be concerned with really :)